# Draw text on bitmap in the bottom left corner

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, drawtext

I'm trying to draw some text on bitmap with a fixed position (Bottom left corner) no matter how bitmap size different.

Code below works but, the Text is drawn on the center of the bitmap

```
public Bitmap drawTextToBitmap(Context gContext,
                               Bitmap bitmap,
                               String gText) {
    Resources resources = gContext.getResources();
    float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
    android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig =
            bitmap.getConfig();
    if (bitmapConfig == null) {
        bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    }
    bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.fujiColor));
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/DS-DIGI.TTF"));
    paint.setTextSize((int) (14 * scale));
    paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, getResources().getColor(R.color.fujiShadowColor));
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(gText, 0, gText.length(), bounds);
    int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2;
    int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height()) / 2;
    canvas.drawText(gText, x, y, paint);
    return bitmap;
}
```

What I need is something similar to this :

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)), the text is drawn taking the (x,y) values as origin. Change the `x`,`y` values. Something along the following lines should work.

```
int horizontalSpacing = 24;
int verticalSpacing = 36;
int x = horizontalSpacing;//(bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2;
int y = bitmap.getHeight()-verticalSpacing;//(bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height()) / 2;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, can you please explain to me why 24 an why 36

Comment: No particular reason, I'm just used to using multiples of 4 or 8 for spacing/sizing ([material design](https://material.io/design/layout/spacing-methods.html#spacing)). The vertical spacing was set higher because characters like y,g,q,etc will have text that 'goes below the origin line'.